# Aligning form elements on right side - text fields and submit button

Tags: css

I have tried many things to try to get the right side of these text fields to align with the submit button, but to no avail.

The button seems to be okay (correct spacing between the button and the frameset border, but the text fields go over.

What could be the problem?

[image: Bad alignment on right side]

```
#loginform {
  width: 580px;
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: #00a0d0 5px solid;
  padding: 30px;
}

.logintextfield {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.loginbutton {
font-size: 1em;
height: 2em;
background-color: #689C41;
width: 100%;
border-top: lightgreen;
border-left: lightgreen;
border-right: darkgreen;
border-bottom: darkgreen;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Update your html code r working fiddle to check.

Comment: As others have suggested, post the actual HTML not just a picture of the current functional issue.

Comment: create a code snippet it would be easy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `box-sizing:border-box` for all elements in your CSS to specify they should have padding and border included in the element's total width and height

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#loginform {
  width: 580px;
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border: #00a0d0 5px solid;
  padding: 30px;
}

.logintextfield {
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.loginbutton {
font-size: 1em;
height: 2em;
background-color: #689C41;
width: 100%;
border-top: lightgreen;
border-left: lightgreen;
border-right: darkgreen;
border-bottom: darkgreen;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<form id="loginform">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>SIGN IN</legend>
    <input type="text" class="logintextfield"><br>
    <input type="text" class="logintextfield"><br>
    <input type="submit" class="loginbutton" value="submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!  This helps me across the board with a lot of alignment and sizing issues.  I can't believe I missed this simple attribute!